# Редактирование записей в бд

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Добрый день. Необходимо производить редактирование данных в базе данных.
Сначала я выбираю нужную таблицу.
HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-3" id = "block3">
    <form id="form_edit">
        <label>Редактирование</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="edit" id = "edit">
            <option value = "category">category</option>
            <option value = "image">image</option>
            <option value = "model">model</option>
            <option value = "news">news</option>
            <option value = "users">users</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" id="edit_send" value = "Редактировать запись">
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    $('#edit_send').on('click',function(){
            var table = $('#edit').val();
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url: "admin_edit_script.php",
                data: {table:table},
                success : function(result){
                    url = "admin_form_edit.php" + '?param1='+table;
                    window.location.href = url;
                },
                error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            })
        }
    );
    <script>
```

Передаю имя таблицы в другой файл и формирую поля.

```
if($_GET["param1"] == 'image') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM image order by id";
    $result = pg_query($connect, $sql);
    echo "<form method = 'post' action = 'admin_edit_script.php'>";
    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<input type = checkbox id = "id" name = "id" value="'.$row["id"].'">
        <input type = "text" id = "primary_name" name = "primary_name" value ="' . $row["primary_name"] . '">
<input type = "text" id = "secondary_name" name = "secondary_name" value ="' . $row["secondary_name"] . '">
<input type = "text" id = "link" name = "link" value ="' . $row["link"] . '">
 <br>';
    }
    echo "<input type='hidden' id = 'table' name = 'table' value = '".$_GET['param1']."'><input type='submit'></form>";
}
```

Как задумывал я. В чекбоксе содержится id записи. При нажатии на кнопку нужно отправить данные в другой файл для выполнения запроса на Update и обновить ту запись, у которой id совпадает с выбранным id. Но по итогу у меня все поля при обновлении получают значения последнего поля.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот на фотографии видно: я отмечал поле и редактировал. Но в итоге все поля получают значения из последних полей. Подозреваю, что это из-за того, что у всех инпутов одинаковые имена.
Сам запрос:

```
    if(($_POST["table"] == "image") and (isset($_POST["id"]))){
   $id = intval($_POST["id"]);
        $sql = "update image set primary_name = '".$_POST["primary_name"]."', secondary_name = '".$_POST["secondary_name"]."', link = '".$_POST["link"]."' where id = '".$id."'";
        $result = pg_query($connect, $sql) or die("fgdgdfg");
    }
```

Подскажите, как всё правильно организовать? Ибо не имел нормального опыта по редактированию данных в таблице через PHP.
Сама таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разумеется все имена должны быть уникальны. Можно использовать например массивы, т.е. имена делать типа id[1], id[2] и т.п. и тогда в GET/POST у вас будут именно массивы значений каждого поля

Comment: А как потом с ними работать при отправке запроса?

Comment: ну у вас например $_POST['id'] будет массивом со значениями по строкам. делаете скажем цикл `for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['id']);$i++)` (ну count() лучше конечно заранее один раз получить, а не в цикле пересчитывать) и внутри берете элементы с номером $i из всех нужных полей POST['id'][$i], POST['link'][$i] и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.

Comment: Можете расписать как для самого тупого человека в мире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала нужно подправить форму, атрибут name полей ввода, должен выглядеть так name="id[]" и так для всех с одинаковыми именами.

А код привести к виду:

```
if($_POST["table"] == "image" and array_key_exists("id", $_POST)){
    foreach ($_POST[id] as $key=>$id) {
        $sql = "update image set primary_name = '".$_POST["primary_name"][$key]."', secondary_name = '".$_POST["secondary_name"][$key]."', link = '".$_POST["link"][$key]."' where id = '".$id."'";
        $result = pg_query($connect, $sql) or die("fgdgdfg");
    }
```

А вообще для таких штук, пристрастился к фреймворкам (Yii2, Laravel, Zend и т.п.). Сам пользовался Yii2. Тяжеловатые, но если нужно что-то быстро собрать для работы с данными в базе, самое то.

Надеюсь помог, удачи!